# Android User Interface Timeout

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application that consist of a number of activities. The application starts with a login screen and if login is successful proceeds through the remaining activities that make up the user interface, generally chained together so that each activity destroys itself after starting the next. If the user is inactive for a period of time (say 30s) I want the application to return to the login activity. I need a background task to run a "watchdog" function that counts up to a limit. When the limit is reached the current activity is destroyed and the login activity started.

The most obvious candidate for this seems to be an IntentService, that can be started at login, as this will run independently of which UI activity is currently active. There are two problems I cannot find a solution to:

1. How do I reset the watchdog time in the IntentService from another activity?
2. How do I get the IntentService to finish() to current UI activity. I assume the simplest way would be to pass which IU was running to the IntentService when the curent activity started.

Both these are similar: is there a way of passing data from an activity to an IntentService while the service is running. I don't think adding another Intent to the queue is what I want.

Or is there a better way of running a background task communicating with different activities providing the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a service. have this running all the time, when you want to start counting load up an intent:

Intent loadedIntent = new Intent (Action.YOUR_REQUIRED_ACTION(defined constant), nullableURI, currentActivity, yourService.class)

then a call to currentActivity.startService(loadedIntent);

Note you can put extras in this which in this instance will help you maintain state when logging back in.

inside your service start method listen for you actions doing a string comparison and then trigger a relevant method and/or handler class depending on what you require.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is one thing I am not sure about. In normal use I would expect user activity to resetting the count frequently as it would be reset on every button click or data entry. The service would be re-called many times during the application. If a startService is sent to a service while it is running does this restart the service?

Comment: @Salvery Yeah it will restart, you have to spawn threads to deal with long running or frequently running tasks. Once you have bound your service onCreate is called when you  call start service onStartCommand is called.

Comment: So initialize all you need in onCreate and then process the startService(intent) in the onStartCommand call.

Comment: That all seems to work now. Thank you for your advice.